# opencart 2.1.0.2 Get order payment-city,addres,country

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

He all, Im implementing in oc 2 an invoice sistem.I have a problem when trying to get the order details.For example in the admin panel ---> view order(admin/view/template/sale/order_info.tpl), I inserted on the bottom of the page this code to generate the "payment city"  `<?php echo $payment_city; ?>`
 and I'm getting this error `Notice: Undefined variable: payment_city in`.
I checked the controller file and there seems to be these codes:

```
$data['payment_city'] = $order_info['payment_city'];
$data['payment_city'] = '';
'city'      => $order_info['payment_city'],
```

Is there a way to generate the order adress but only specific thiqs like city, country. etc not all of them.

Comment: Are you fetching $order info from database before using this code? You can also use this Opencart pdf invoice which allows you to customize invoice. 

https://www.knowband.com/opencart-pdf-invoice

Comment: Hey, yes from the database, thqs for your suggestion but I'm implementing that cod for a cloudbase invoice system.